# Using Japanese On Screen Vitrual Keyboard in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internationalization, virtual-keyboard

I want to test my software compatibility with `Japanese` apps, and I don't have neither Japanese keyboard, nor Japanese knowledge.

Is there anything like `Japanese On Screen Virtual Keyboard` in `Windows 7`. 
If yes how to enable it in windows. 
If not any other ways third party software for getting the virtual keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can input Japanese without Japanese keyboard or virtual one, on Windows 7. This site http://www.coscom.co.jp/learnjapanese801/howtotypejapanese.html would help you.